# svn giving http bad request on specific file extensions

Tags: apache, svn, ankhsvn

For a little while now we are getting an error when trying to commit our code to svn. I have been searching for a solution but cannot find any. The error I am getting is this:

*StackTrace of AnkhSVN:*

```
SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad request' on '/repos/RTL/!svn/wrk/f081208b-2e92-7e4e-af03-efe2bdd121df/LoadBalancedDataProcessor/DataProcessor/App.config'
 at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
 at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
 at SharpSvn.SvnClient.RemoteImport(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
 at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Import(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
 at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Import(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args)
 at Ankh.Commands.AddToSccCommands.<>c__DisplayClassd.<CheckoutWorkingCopyForSolution>b__a(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs a)
 at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

Only the files with extension *.config are not committed. If we exclude these files, everything seems to work.

We are using svn 1.8.10 with apache 2.4.10 on Raspbian 8.0 and we are trying to commit my source code with Ankhsvn 2.6.12730.10 on Visual Studio 2013.

Does anybody have a clue what might be going on here?

**EDIT:**

I found out that it has something to do with mod_mono in the Apache configuration. However I did not find the solution yet.

TIA

Comment: Is Apache configured to reject files with that extension?

Comment: I would start by looking in the apache error log. This probably provides some clues on how to fix this. Are you sure there is no proxy server involved? (asp.net typically blocks this extension unless explicitly configured)

Comment: It used to work and I have not added anything to Apache to prevent the extension. There is no proxy either. I am not trying to commit an asp.net project, but a windows service project.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the antivirus software.

Comment: I found out that it has something to with Mono that was installed as well. I still need to figure out what is causing it in the Mono configuration.